# How do I exit an archive in no-window mode?

Tags: navigation, archive-mode

When navigating the directory structure in no window mode, there is always `..` at the top of the current directory, so that one can leave it and go to the directory up ahead.

I am using emacs 26.3 and when I enter a zip archive, I see no way of leaving the archive other exiting emacs using `C-x C-c`.

How do I leave the archive properly, so that I end up back in the directory where the archive is stored?

Comment: Does pressing the letter `q` help any?

Answer (score 1):

`q` in `Zip-Archive` mode will run command `quit-window`. You can see information about enabled modes by invoking `describe-mode` (`C-h m`).

Your zip archive is a separate buffer along with dired one so usual commands to work with buffers can also help:

- `C-x b <RET>` (`switch-to-buffer`) will switch to previous buffer (dired)
- `C-x k <RET>` (`kill-buffer`) will kill current buffer (zip archive)